# How to validate if an Array of strings is sorted in alphabetical order or not using java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

How to validate the String is in alphabetical order or not? It is just to validate that String is in order or not?

**Can anybody help me how to validate?**
Here is my code::

```
public class Example3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Month[]={"Jan", "Add", "Siri", "Xenon", "Cat"};

        for(int i=0; i<Month.length; i++) {     
            System.out.println(Month[i]);                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by alphabetical order?

Comment: Sure. For ex : When I get the text from any dropdown list I'll get the all options text. I'm storing those values in a String like this                                                                                                  String str=single.getText();
System.out.println(str);                                                                               --->The o/p of the str=Jan,Add,Xenon                                                                                    Now I want to validate that 'str' is in order or not.

Answer (score 6):

You could get the `i`-th (i >= 1) element and apply [`compareTo(String other)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) against the previous one:

```
boolean ordered = true;
for (int i = 1; i < month.length; i++) {
    if (month[i].compareTo(month[i - 1]) < 0) {
         ordered = false;
         break;
    }
}

System.out.println(ordered ? "Ordered" : "Unordered");
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a loop, just use `Collections` to compare them since the `equals` method works fine with this type of objects.

---

### Solution

```
String[] Month={"Jan", "Add", "Siri", "Xenon", "Cat"};
List<String> copyOf = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Month));
Collections.sort(copyOf);
if (Arrays.asList(Month).equals(copyOf)){
    System.out.println("Sorted");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not sorted"); // Not sorted of course but if Month
                                      // was {"Add", "Siri"} it would've been true
}
```